# class_exists is calling spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, spl, autoloader, spl-autoload-register

I create a simple script for autoload classes, but when I use `class_exists` the `spl_autoload_register` is executed, example:

```
<?php
function autoLoadClass($name) {
    echo 'spl_autoload_register: ', $name, '<br>';
}

spl_autoload_register('autoLoadClass');

class_exists('Foo');
class_exists('Bar');
class_exists('Foo\\Bar');
```

Output:

> spl_autoload_register: Foo
>   spl_autoload_register: Bar
>   spl_autoload_register: Foo\Bar

Is that right? Is there any way to make "spl_autoload" ignore calls "class_exists"?

Comment: You have a question about `class_exists` so why don't you look up the manual page for it?!

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks for *discouraging*.

Comment: My comment shouldn't discourage you. It should be more a bit of a reminder/info to always check the manual if you have a question/problem with a certain function.

Comment: @Rizier123 So bad questions here with positive votes. Right? However, some actions where only *discourage*. Believe I always read the manual, only it was a lack of attention and I think the question still rather helped formulate a good answer, which in addition to containing the manual contains an alternative example. Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can make `class_exists` not call autoloading.
From [the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php):

> bool class_exists ( string $class_name **[, bool $autoload = true ]** )

So a call like:

```
class_exists('Foo', false);
```

would ignore autoloading.

**[ [Demo](https://3v4l.org/KSVXr) ]**

It is also *possible* to make the autoloading function ignore calls from `class_exists` by (ab)using `debug_backtrace`, but that method is ugly and really slow, but for the sake of completeness, here's how to do it:

```
function autoLoadClass($name) {
    foreach(debug_backtrace() as $call) {
        if(!array_key_exists('type', $call) && $call['function'] == 'class_exists') {
            return;
        }
    }
    echo 'spl_autoload_register: ', $name, '<br>';
}
```

*(Note: This doesn't seem to work in HHVM)*

That basically aborts the function if one of the calling functions is called `class_exists`, and the `$call['type']` must not exist to make sure that calls like `SomeClass::class_exists` and `$someObject->class_exists` are filtered out.

**[ [Demo](https://3v4l.org/MYmq7) ]**

Comment: Good example with `debug_backtrace` :) Thanks - But `class_exists(..., false);` that's enough. However it is a good example to study. Thank you for encouraging and provide a good answer, unlike the others users.